# Using MOD with Time values to determine time differences that transition midnight

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, excel-2010

I created an Excel Spreadsheet with a Total Time for the Duration of the Shift ie 8:30-17:30.

Then I created this formula

```
=(MOD([@[Supposed Shift End]]-[@[Supposed Shift Start]],1))*24
```

with Format cells -> Number 2 decimal places. This gives me the [Total Supposed Shift Hours]

Giving me Duration of the Shift that needs to be covered.

Now I also created another column for the ACTUAL time the shift covered

```
=(MOD([@[Actual Time End]]-[@[Actual Time Start]],1))*24
```

This gives me the [Total Actual Time Hours]

For the Actual Time End and Actual Time Start When the employee DIDN'T show up we entered 0 for both cells with the same cell format Number -> 2 decimal places

The Problem:

This is the formula I wrote to subtract these 2 Columns

```
=(MOD([@[Total Supposed Shift Hours]]-[@[Total Actual Time Hours]],1))*24
```

Why when I subtract say the [Total Supposed Shift Hours] 9.00 - the [Total Actual Time Hours] 0.00 = 24.00 ???

9 - 0 = 9 not 24.... sigh

Will the formula be affected if the time  goes from previous night 21:00 to 8:00 with the MOD formula?

**Sample data** (as requested)
Note: Nomenclature differs from description above: `Open` = `Supposed` and `Covered` = `Actual`

| Service Date | Open Post Start | Open Post End | Total Hrs Missing | Covered Post Start | Covered Post End | Total Hrs Covered | Category | Hours Not Covered |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02/06/2021 | 16:00 | 00:00 | 8 | 16:00 | 03:00 | 11 | A | 0 |
| 04/06/2021 | 16:00 | 00:00 | 8 | 00:00 | 00:00 | 0 | A | 0 |
| 10/21/2021 | 10:30 | 00:00 | 13.5 | 18:00 | 19:30 | 1.5 | B | 0 |

Comment: Sorry I am not sure if Mr. Craner answered the question? I just saw something edited. If Mr. Craner did correct something then maybe I missed his advice or help?

Comment: So P.b how do I fix this? Please help?

Comment: Question though P.b but if the time goes from 16:00 to 0:00 which is 8 hours. Multiplying that by 24 I see this huge number 287984.00..... What the? Help again?

Comment: Import question (since you have shown any sample data): Are `Times` expressed as `Time` only (e.g: `16:00`) or `Date and Time` (e,g, `01/01/2021 16:00`)?

Comment: Currently 16:00 is expressed as Time and 13:30 as Cell Format.... And Spinner how can I fix this? sigh I initially used the MOD formula because it fixes the time calculation problem from the previous evening to the next morning ie 16:00 pm to 8:00am for example. Now removing the MOD formula gives me that huge number. In addition I thought about JUST using the FORMULA for the 6 errors I have but my spreadsheet auto fills rest of the cells in the column with that MOD formula..... HELP!!

Comment: Sure you can. Tell me: What is it that your formula `=(MOD([@[Total Supposed Shift Hours]]-[@[Total Actual Time Hours]],1))*24` is trying to determine?

Comment: I am essentially trying to calculate for over thousands of shifts on this spreadsheet when the Shift started and Shift ended say from 16:00 pm to 0:00 (12am). The MOD formula is supposedly give the absolute value of hours and multiplying that by 24 gives me a Numeric value. I am trying to distill the time (hours) into a Numeric value :)

Comment: You misread my question. Your first 2 formulas (as you already know) work as is and I understand what they are seeking to do. My question is about the 3rd formula (i.e. the one that doesn't work): What is it trying to determine? It reads as if it simply wants the difference (in hours) between `Supposed` and `Actual`. Is that what it's trying to do?

Comment: Sorry let me rephrase my question. Since I initially used the MOD formula for 3 Columns Column E, H and J. So Columns C and D: Column C gives me When the Shift Supposed to Start and Column D is when the Shift Supposed to End (Duration of the Shift assignment) respectively then Column E totals the hours where the MOD Formula is used. The HUGE number error occurred for the Column E. Column F and G gives the Actual Time Employee actually showed up for the shift (F) and Actual time left the shift (G). Column H uses the MOD Formula again to calculate the Actual Time the employee showed up and left.

Comment: Finally Column J also uses the MOD formula to Total / Sum Column E and H. The huge number error shows up for Column E and J. Not H for some strange reason.

Comment: @Spinner I provided the sample by editing the original post. And P.b I am still not sure how to embed that (1+0)*24 into my formula? Sorry if I am not getting it.

Comment: @P.b I cannot just fix the 6 cells with that error because somehow my spreadsheet Auto fills the other cells in the same column with the same formula? I also provided a sample of my spreadsheet in my original post if that helps? :)

Comment: @P.b and QED_Millenium: Can we unwind (i.e. delete) all the stuff related to removal of `MOD` please? It was a complete red herring, and for any future readers simply cause for confusion and unnecessary reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Initial Answer**
A minor point first: You don't need to wrap the `MOD` function in brackets. As the function already produces a result to the `*24`. Thus the following works just fine:

```
=MOD([@[Supposed Time End]]-[@[Supposed Time Start]],1)*24
```

To your question: Your non-working formula reads as if it simply wants the difference (in hours) between `Supposed` and `Actual`. If that's so, simply do this:

```
=[@[Total Supposed Shift Hours]]-[@[Total Actual Shift Hours]]
```

**EDIT**: Using the (now posted) table, I've constructed what I think it is you're trying to do
Refer to *Sample results* image below.

Formula in Colum E: `=MOD([@[Open Post End]]-[@[Open Post Start]],1)*24`
Formula in Colum H: `=MOD([@[Covered Post End]]-[@[Covered Post Start]],1)*24`
Formula in Colum J: `=[@[Total Hours Missing]]-[@[Total Hours Covered]]`

**Sample results**:

[image]

**Now**: If Column J (i.e. the response to your core question) isn't the result you're after, can you tell me what it is you would expect there (using actual expected values for each row).

Notes:

1. Your table column header `Total Hours Missing` is somewhat confusing.
   But, I'm reading that a `Post Duration` (`Duration of Shift` in your original parlance).
2. If I understand what transpired correctly, the "spanner in the works" was @P.b suggestion to remove `MOD`. Revert your formulas in columns `E` and `H` as shown above.

Comment: Sorry @Spinner I forgot to mention when the employee didnt show up we entered 0:00 for Covered Post Start Time and Covered Post End time (for not showing up). When I went with P.b's first suggestion removing the MOD formula and just multiplying the Total Hours Missing with just *24 then I get that huge number error.

Comment: I used P.b's suggestion into my formula so his suggestion (it was my fault for not mentioning the 0:00 for no shows...) So that threw a wrench into my formula for time calculation.

Comment: Thank you @Spinner just a quick question. How can I write something in a new column when the Total Hours covered is greater than 8 hours then I can subtract one hour from the Total Hours Covered? I wrote this: =IF([@[Covered Post End]]-[@[Covered Post Start]]>DATEVALUE(8:00),((MOD([@[Covered Post Start]]-[@[Covered Post End]],1))*24)-1,[@[Total Hr Covered]]). I am not sure why I am getting an error because I am asking the IF statement if the hours worked is greater than 8 hours subtract one hour.

Comment: Not sure what your actually looking to do there, but `DATEVALUE(8:00)` is invalid. For that notion, you'd use `TIMEVALUE("08:00")`. But why not just test the hours, i.e.: `IF([@[Total Hours Covered]]>8`

Comment: Thank you both @Spinner and P.b for helping me! Really appreciate the clarification and guidance on this thread! ^_^ Cheers mate!